# Redirecting with header, but http code is always 200

Tags: php, http

So, I have a page that checks if the user is logged in and if he isn't they are redirected to the error page with code 403. This is the code I use to redirect:

```
header('Location: /error.php', true, 403);
```

But, instead of redirecting it only sets the code to 403. And if I try:

```
header('HTTP/1.1 403 FORBIDDEN');
header('Location: /error.php');
```

Then it redirects, but the code is 200...
I'm really lost here and couldn't find anything that worked.

ps: this is my error.php page

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/error.css">
<?php if (http_response_code() === 404) : ?>
<div class="error">404</div>
<br /><br />
<span class="info">File not found</span>
<img src="http://images2.layoutsparks.com/1/160030/too-much-tv-static.gif" class="static" />
<?php elseif (http_response_code() === 403) : ?>
<div class="error">403</div>
<br /><br />
<span class="info">Unauthorized access</span>
<img src="http://images2.layoutsparks.com/1/160030/too-much-tv-static.gif" class="static" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use redirection, but script reuse.

Redirection means "What you are looking for, can be found at a different place". You don't want to send the user to a different place. You want to tell them that they are not allowed to see that place where they tried to go.

Instead, use `require` to include the php script which should show information about an error to the user, without changing the URI.

```
if(detectedUserNotAllowed)
{
   header('HTTP/1.1 403 FORBIDDEN');
   require("error.php");
   exit();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

From the docs:

> From the docs: "The second special case is the "Location:" header. Not only does it send this header back to the browser, but it also returns a REDIRECT (302) status code to the browser unless the 201 or a 3xx status code has already been set.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

That being said, you can add the header in your `error.php` page

```
header("HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden");
```

Comment: yes, I could, but the thing i forgot to say in the question was that I am using this error page for multiple error codes. So I wanted to set it before it got to the page, so that it would show the correct error code

Comment: Then create multiple errors page like `error403.php` `error500.php` and so on. These pages can `include` another page code inside, after set the header.

Answer (score 1):

You don't redirect - you simply generate the 403 (or whatever other error code is appropriate) and have Apache send the proper `ErrorDocument`.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#errordocument

EG -

```
ErrorDocument 403 /errors/forbidden.php?referrer=%{escape:%{HTTP_REFERER}}
```

in your Apache vhost config, or a .htaccess file.

Even Apache's docs note what one of the comments reflected about sending a status code followed by a redirect -

> Note that when you specify an ErrorDocument that points to a remote
>   URL (ie. anything with a method such as http in front of it), Apache
>   HTTP Server will send a redirect to the client to tell it where to
>   find the document, even if the document ends up being on the same
>   server. This has several implications, the most important being that
>   the client will not receive the original error status code, but
>   instead will receive a redirect status code. This in turn can confuse
>   web robots and other clients which try to determine if a URL is valid
>   using the status code. In addition, if you use a remote URL in an
>   ErrorDocument 401, the client will not know to prompt the user for a
>   password since it will not receive the 401 status code. Therefore, if
>   you use an ErrorDocument 401 directive, then it must refer to a local
>   document.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot redirect with a `403` code, browsers won't heed a location header if the status code is not one of the `3xx` section.

This is found in [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-7.1.2):

> For 3xx (Redirection) responses,    the Location value refers to the
> preferred target resource for    automatically redirecting the
> request.